# Pivot Rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

My dataframe currently looks like:

```
ID               FIELD        VALUE
12463634          TEST         22.2 
12463634      E_REASON          010
12463634      IN_SCOPE            Y
12463635          TEST         99.5 
12463635      E_REASON          020
12463635      IN_SCOPE            N
```

I'd like my dataframe to look like:

```
ID           TEST     E_REASON     IN_SCOPE
12463634     22.2          010            Y
12463635     99.5          020            N
```

I have tried running this code:

```
df.pivot_table(index = "ID", columns = "FIELD", values = "VALUE")
```

However, I am seeing this error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: I think possibly what you may want is `pivot` rather than `pivot_table`.

Comment: Only if they make non-unique indices. I just tried it and pivot works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index = "ID", columns = "FIELD", values = "VALUE")
print (df)
FIELD    E_REASON IN_SCOPE  TEST
ID                              
12463634      010        Y  22.2
12463635      020        N  99.5
```

---

```
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'FIELD'])['VALUE'].unstack()
print (df)
FIELD    E_REASON IN_SCOPE  TEST
ID                              
12463634      010        Y  22.2
12463635      020        N  99.5
```

If duplicates need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function - `sum` or `','join`:

```
print (df)
         ID     FIELD VALUE
0  12463634      TEST  22.2
1  12463634  E_REASON   010
2  12463634  IN_SCOPE     Y<-same ID and FIELED
3  12463634  IN_SCOPE    Y1<-same ID and FIELED
4  12463635      TEST  99.5
5  12463635  E_REASON   020
6  12463635  IN_SCOPE     N


df = df.pivot_table(index = "ID", columns = "FIELD", values = "VALUE", aggfunc='sum')
print (df)
FIELD    E_REASON IN_SCOPE  TEST
ID                              
12463634      010      YY1  22.2
12463635      020        N  99.5
```

Or:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index = "ID", columns = "FIELD", values = "VALUE", aggfunc=','.join)
print (df)
FIELD    E_REASON IN_SCOPE  TEST
ID                              
12463634      010     Y,Y1  22.2
12463635      020        N  99.5
```

Comment: pivot worked just fine - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to do something like:

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'FIELD']).sum().unstack()
```

This way you don't lose the label `'VALUES'`

## Explanation

You can `groupby` and `sum()` which will give you

```
In [31]: df.groupby(['ID', 'FIELD']).sum()
Out[31]:
                  VALUE
ID       FIELD
12463634 E_REASON   010
         IN_SCOPE     Y
         TEST      22.2
12463635 E_REASON   020
         IN_SCOPE     N
         TEST      99.5
```

Then the `unstack` moves the last indexed row to a column